# Converting <li> tags to horizontal responsive barcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugin

I am writing my first jQuery plugin that converts `li` tags to horizontal responsive barcharts. I am looking for some feedback and suggestions regarding the implementation.

[image: barcharts example]

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.barcharts = function(options) {

        // Establish default settings
        var defaults = {
            animationSpeed  : 500
        };

        // Merge
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        // Gather
        var $targets = $(this).find('.bar-group-item');

        // Render
        $.each($targets, function() {

            var $li = $(this),
                newWidth = $li.data('bar-value')/100*$li.width();            

            // Construct the item to be displayed
            var $div = $('<div>', {     
                width: 0,       
                text: $li.text()
            });

            // Remove previous contents
            $li.empty();

            // Append to current item
            $div.appendTo($li);

            // Reveal
            $div.animate({width: newWidth}, options.animationSpeed);

        }); 
    };

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.bar-group {    
    list-style: none;
    padding-left:0;
}

.bar-group-item {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #34495e;
    color: #ffffff;    
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.bar-group-item div {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bar-group">
    <li class="bar-group-item" data-bar-value="15">England</li>
    <li class="bar-group-item" data-bar-value="25">Spain</li>
    <li class="bar-group-item" data-bar-value="85">Zimbabwe</li>
</ul>
<ul class="bar-group">
    <li class="bar-group-item" data-bar-value="32">Lakers</li>
    <li class="bar-group-item" data-bar-value="62">Heat</li>
    <li class="bar-group-item" data-bar-value="95">Raptors</li>
</ul>
<ul class="bar-group">
    <li class="bar-group-item" data-bar-value="33">Los Angeles</li>
    <li class="bar-group-item" data-bar-value="33">Miami</li>
    <li class="bar-group-item" data-bar-value="100">Toronto</li>
</ul>  

<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.bar-group').barcharts();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Jack where should i post it then?

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice it was already in the right spot :)

Comment: Would be nice if you could update existing bars

Comment: @Jack that's a pretty good idea, thanks. Also, do you have any comments about the code?

Comment: The only thing I notice off hand is the use of `.animate();` http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/ I'd try to pass it off to the css layer or use js where possible for animations. Nice little plugin, good work.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you to get rid of class selector here

```
// Gather
var $targets = $(this).find('.bar-group-item');
```

because you need you're HTML structure to use specific classes. You'd better find them by finding elements with data attributes inside plugin's target element.

Scalability!